# What are the names of the characters in Gurren Lagann derived from? And how do they relate to the characters?

Tags: gurren-lagann

The second DVD of the first movie *Gurren Lagann The Movie: Childhood's End*, and also one of the disc in Complete Bluray Box Set feature [a quiz session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMJnAoKDKSw&t=2m18s) between the voice actors for *Youko* (Inoue Marina), *Shimon* (Kakihara Tetsuya) and *Kamina* (Konishi Katsuyuki) about various details in the anime.

In the first quiz of the show, it is mentioned that one of the special features in *Gurren Lagann* is the names of the characters: [シモン]{Shimon} comes up [下]｛Shimo｝ (down), [カミナ]{Kamina}　comes up [上]{Kami} (up), and the answer to the quiz reveals that [リーロン]{Leeron} comes from [論理]{Ronri} (logic).

How about other characters in Gurren Lagann? What are their names derived from, and how do they relate to the characters?

<sup>Feel free to explain the relation between the names and the characters already mentioned above.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

### [Nia](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Nia_Tepplin)

> Nia's name has multiple potential origins.
>
> - Her name in Japanese could also be read as Near. Referring to her relationship with Simon.
> - Nia's name by itself can also be seen as a short version of other feminine names ending with Nia such as Antonia or Stefania.
> - Her name is also present in the Swahili language, where it means purpose. Referencing her role as the Anti-Spirals' messenger. It could also possibly refer to the fact that, in one way or another, she motivates Simon (and by extension, the rest of Team Dai-Gurren) to overcome impossible odds time and again.
> - Nia's name could also be considered as a Welsh variant of the Irish name Niamh (pronounced "neev"), which means bright or radiant. Possibly referencing her appearance and/or her personality prior to the Anti-Spiral War and during her captivity on the Anti-Spiral homeworld as well as events that follow. The name Niamh, in turn, originates from the Irish mythological figure Níamh Chinn Óir. (Also known as Niamh of the Golden Hair, and known by the Welsh as Nia Ben Aur.) Who, according to legend, is said to be the daughter of the Irish sea god Manannán mac Lir, the wife of Oisín, the mother of Plor na mBan and Oscar, and one of the queens of Tír na nÓg, The Land of Youth.

### [Viral](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Viral)

> Viral's name comes directly from the word "viral", tying in with the Beastmen's genetics theme, but there are other theories about his name's origin.
>
> - One is the fact that it can also be an anagram for "rival", referring to his constant rivalry with Kamina, which transferred to Simon throughout the series until near the end.
> - Another possible theory comes from the Nikopol Trilogy of comic books written by Enki Bilal, as Enki is the name of Viral's first Gunmen and "Bilal", pronounced in Japanese, sounds like "Viral". Supporting this theory is Viral's theme song, which is titled "Nikopol", on the anime's soundtrack.
>
> The name of Viral's Ganmen may be tied to the Sumerian deity Enki, though it is much more likely that there is a deliberate connection between his second Gunmen, Enkidu, and the character of Enkidu from the Epic of Gilgamesh. The myth consists of Enkidu ('Enki's creation'), a man of the wild who seeks to challenge King Gilgamesh, a mighty warrior, but who later befriends him and assists him in in his travels, which may be a reference to Simon and Kamina, as he initially wanted to beat them but later joined Simon to save the universe.

### [Lordgenome](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Lordgenome)

> Lordgenome's name comes from the English "lord" (a male noble) and "genome", the blueprint for an organism found in its DNA. For this reason, many people spell his name as "Lord Genome". The name is meant to tie in with theme of biology for Lordgenome's inner circle with each of his generals getting his/her name from one of the nitrogen bases that make up DNA, as well as reflecting upon his position as a king on Planet Earth. Lordgenome's name was combined by Gainax to reduce confusion among Japanese readers about "lord" being a title, rather than a part of the character's first name.

### [Kiyal Bachika](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Kiyal_Bachika)

> Kiyal's name comes from yaruki meaning 'willingness'

### [Thymilph](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Thymilph)

> Thymilph's name is based on the DNA chemical thymine and the elemental Sylph. His Ganmen, Byakou, is based on the mythical White Tiger, Byakko.

### [Adiane](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Adiane)

> Adiane's name (pronounced "Ah-DEE-NAY") is based on the DNA chemical adenine and the water elemental, Undine. Her Ganmen, Sayrune, is based on the mythical Azure Dragon, Seiryū.

### [Cytomander](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Cytomander)

> Cytomander's name (pronounced See-toh-man-dra) is based on the DNA chemical Cytosine and the elemental Salamander. His Ganmen, Shuzack, is based on the mythical Vermilion Bird, Suzaku.

### [Guame](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Guame)

> Guame's name is based on the DNA chemical Guanine and Gnome, the earth spirit. His Ganmen, Gember, is based on the mythical Black Tortoise, Genbu.

Source: [Gurren Lagann Wiki](http://gurrenlagann.wikia.com/wiki/Characters).